# Windows VM on Linux with dedicated GPU and memory

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, multi-boot, gpu, linux-kvm

I'm building a new PC. I want windows for gaming and some C++ work targeting the hololens. However, my primary development machine would be linux.

I have 32Gb ram, 2 x 1tb m.2 memory, one 3080 and no integrated graphics.

I would rather not dual boot as then I need to restart whenever I want to game and potentially get hit with lengthy windows updates. A VM is attractive as it would let me switch quickly between the 2 workflows.

I want the best performance I can get. Is a VM with GPU passthrough and a dedicated drive a good alternative to dual booting? If so, how do I set up the VM (specifically so it has sole access to the drive and GPU)?

Comment: @Ramhound would I be able to reclaim the GPU on the linux install once I exit out of the VM?

Comment: @Ramhound there are some guys on reddit suggesting that I need to play with the xserver to make that happen. I've set up headless installs before for embedded devices but the purpose of those was to have GPU acceleration on a headless device. This is all pretty new to me. You're the first person I've seen saying this would leave me with a headless linux install. I was under the impression linux would stop acting as an OS if I were to use KVM.

Comment: @Ramhound leave this as an answer and I'll accept it, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The VM is an alternative, but it's impossible to tell which solution will
be the best for performance, at least not without doing a benchmark.
I don't think that a dedicated drive is a must.

You can find the details on doing so under Ubuntu in the article
[Beginner friendly guide to windows virtual machines with GPU passthrough on Ubuntu 18.04](https://mathiashueber.com/windows-virtual-machine-gpu-passthrough-ubuntu/).

You should check well all the requirements of such a setup.
You would also be unable to use the passed GPU in the host,
so the computer will need to have at least two GPUs.